# Get more info of installed app

Tags: android, android-intent, package-managers

I know in Android, I can invoke `getInstalledPackages(0)` of [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) API to get all the installed apps on device.

I am wondering is there a way or workaround to get the publisher's name of installed app by using Android SDK (i.e. no 3rd party library)??

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct way to do that. Because that information is not available anywhere in the manifest or source code.

As a workaround, you can get the process name/package name, and find publishers name from google [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube):

Pseudo code:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> appInfos = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);

for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : appInfos) {
    String processName = appInfo.processName; // Example: com.google.android.youtube
    String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + processName;
    // Fetch publisher name from web here
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The package that contains related classes, especially ApplicationInfo, there is no public interface for this (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/package-summary.html). So i belive there's no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no android API to get the publisher's name of the application. You can get the publisher's and more information from the play store using this 3rd party API.

https://api.appmonsta.com/v1/stores/android/details/your-package-name.json?country=us

Replace the 'your-package-name' from API to the application package name.
First, you have to register with api.appmonsta.com to run this API.

Comment: asking for user name and password

Comment: Yes, You have to register your app to appmonsta and get the API key.  This API key is used as a username and a password is optional.
Or if you don't want to use third party api, so you can use the below link to get HTML page
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + package-name
In this case, you have to parse the HTML tags and get the value from them.